# Prepend folder name to paths in an array

Tags: windows, powershell, filenames, string-concatenation, prepend

I'm looking to prepend a folder name to the start of an array of (relative) paths using a foreach statement, but it's not making any changes to the array (no errors either)

Note: This is more for educational purposes than functional as I have it working using a for loop which I've commented out, but I'm interested in learning how the foreach statement works

```
$myFiles = @(
    "blah1\blah2\file1.txt"
    "blah3\blah4\file2.txt"
    "blah5\blah6\file3.txt"
)

$checkoutFolder = "folder1"

#for ($h = 0; $h -lt $myFiles.Length; $h++) {
#$myFiles[$h] = $checkoutFolder + "\" + $myFiles[$h]
#}

foreach ($path in $myFiles) {
$path = $checkoutFolder + "\" + $path
}

$myFiles
```

I also tried using a buffer variable e.g.

```
$buffer = $checkoutFolder + "\" + $path
$path = $buffer
```

But same result i.e.
OUTPUT:

```
blah1\blah2\file1.txt
blah3\blah4\file2.txt
blah5\blah6\file3.txt
```

Comment: your primary problem is re-using the "current loop item" in your loop. **_do not do that unless you have a need to do so_**. [*grin*] your `$Buffer` has what you need ... so use it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of two ways:

Create new array with modified data of old array

```
$myFiles = @(
            "blah1\blah2\file1.txt"
            "blah3\blah4\file2.txt"
            "blah5\blah6\file3.txt"
            )
$checkoutFolder = "folder1"

#Create new array $myFilesnew
$myFilesnew = @()
#For each line in in old array
foreach ($file in $myFiles)
{
#Create new row from modied row $file of $myFiles array
$row = $checkoutFolder+"\"+$file
#Add row $row to a new array $myFilesnew
$myFilesnew+=$row
}

$myFilesnew
```

Modify each row of existing array:

```
$myFiles = @(
            "blah1\blah2\file1.txt"
            "blah3\blah4\file2.txt"
            "blah5\blah6\file3.txt"
            )
$checkoutFolder = "folder1"

$i=0
while($i-lt $myFiles.Count)
    {
     #Get $i row $myFiles[$i] from aray, perform insert of modified data, write data back to $myFiles[$i] row of the array
     $myfiles[$i]=$myFiles[$i].Insert(0,$checkoutFolder+"\");
     #Add +1 to $i
     $i++

        }
$myFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Better start using the `Join-Path` cmdlet to avoid creating paths with backslashes omitted or doubled.

Something like this would do it:

```
$checkoutFolder = "folder1"
$myFiles = "blah1\blah2\file1.txt", "blah3\blah4\file2.txt", "blah5\blah6\file3.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Join-Path -Path $checkoutFolder -ChildPath $_
}

$myFiles
```

output:

> ```
> folder1\blah1\blah2\file1.txt
> folder1\blah3\blah4\file2.txt
> folder1\blah5\blah6\file3.txt
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the regex beginning of each string with the folder name. This is a useful idiom for generating computernames too.

```
'blah1\blah2\file1.txt','blah3\blah4\file2.txt','blah5\blah6\file3.txt' -replace '^','folder1\'

folder1\blah1\blah2\file1.txt
folder1\blah3\blah4\file2.txt
folder1\blah5\blah6\file3.txt
```